# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '26 ( cid int(11) not null, ' at line 1 sql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am making a website where people can learn to code by completing courses so I need a table for just one user and a table for all the user info. When creating the table just for the user (in PHP) I get this error from the mysqli_error function in PHP:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '30 ( cid int(100) not null, ' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
create table $rowid (
    cid int(100) not null,
    com TEXT not null,
    page int(100) not null,
    title TEXT not null
);
```

I have set the rowid variable to their id in the user info table. When I do it from PHPMyAdmin (but replace the rowid with something else) it works fine.
What is wrong with the SQL or PHP code?

Comment: still does not work. I did not think it would because i have already tried this

Comment: The error says it is with the cid column

Comment: What is the value of `$rowid` when the above script executes and fails?

Comment: Check the value of $rowid which is showing `30` in your error. Table name can not be numeric

Comment: @Alien10 You usually don't create tables dynamically like you did, but instead create one table with a column `userId`. That way you can link the entries to a specific user.

Comment: That is a bad database design. Don't create tables for each user. It's not how RDBMS works.

Answer (score 1):

26 is not a valid table name. "Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits. ". See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html for more info on identifiers. PhpAdmin probably quotes that with backticks for you.